# code who can find the biggest of the 5 numbers

Tags: java

I am new here and
I must write a code who can find the biggest of the 5 numbers who put the user. I have write something but it is not working. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // import java.lang.Math;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input 5 integers: ");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
    int z = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
    int m = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine()); 
    int n = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine()); 
    int max = Math.max(x,y);

    if (x>y && x>z && x>m && x>n)
        System.out.println ("The first of your numbers is the bigest");

    else if(y>x && y>z && y>m && y>n)
        System.out.println ("The second of your numbers is the bigest");

    else if (z>x && z>y && z>m && z>n)
         System.out.println ("The third of your numbers is the bigest");

    else if (m>x && m>y && m>z && m>n)
         System.out.println ("The fourth of your numbers is the bigest");

    else if (n>x && n>y && n>z && n>m)
         System.out.println ("The fifth of your numbers is the bigest");




    System.out.println("The max of three is: " + max);
```

Comment: I guess you intend to assign `max = ...` in the conditions, e.g. `max = x;` in the first one. Note that you also need to handle the case that two (or more) of them are equal and largest.

Comment: Can you use a `List<Integer>`?

Comment: You want to use `>=` instead of `>`.

Comment: int max = Math.max(x,Math.max(y,Math.max(z,Math.max(m,n))));

Answer (score 2):

Let the `Collections` class does it for you :)

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(x,y,z,m,n);
int max = Collections.max(list).intValue();
System.out.println("And the winner is: " + max);
```

If you want to find also the position in the collection you should do as follow:

```
int index = list.indexOf(max);
String[]position={"first","second","third","fourth","fifth"};
System.out.println("The "+position[index]+" of your numbers is the bigest");
```

Comment: You should also show OP how to find the index of the largest value

Answer (score 0):

You only find maximum of x and y and print it in the end. You should assign new values to max in each conditions(in if - else if statements). For example in first condition, if x is bigger than y, z, m and n, you should assign x to max.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this can be answered with Collections.max() this looks like homework which is probably looking for a more nuts-and-bolts approach such as ....

```
int [] array = {x, y, z, m , n};

int largest = x;
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > largest) {
        largest = array[i];
        index = i;
    }
}
System.out.println("Largest found at index " + index);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have used `Math.max()` which means you are allowed to use it and you may make full use of it. In case you cannot use array or other data structures, you may consider this:

To get the maximum of the 5 numbers, you can do this:

```
int largest = Math.max(Math.max (Math.max(x,y), Math.max(m,n)), z);
```

To print the position of the largest:

```
String pos = "";
switch(largest){
    case x: pos = "first";
            break;
    case y: pos = "second";
            break;
    case z: pos = "third";
            break;
    case m: pos = "forth";
            break;
    case n: pos = "fifth";
            break;
};

System.out.println ("The " + pos " + of your numbers is the biggest");
```